# determine the Laplace domain of this RL circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform

[image]

I am currently learning control system design. I have a lot of confusion about the initial conditions of the inductor in the circuit. Could someone please correctly solve this by getting the differential equations and then take the Laplace transform.

Comment: You must show your attempt at constructing the differential equation. For the initial condition, assume the circuit has been connected for a long time, therefore the initial current is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction), we can write:

$$-\text{V}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{d}\left(t\right)+\text{R}\cdot\text{I}\left(t\right)=-\text{L}\cdot\text{I}'\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Where \$\text{I}\left(t\right)\$ is the input current (which is the same trough all the components because it is a series circuit).

Using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) we can write:

$$-\text{v}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{v}_\text{d}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{R}\cdot\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=-\text{L}\cdot\left(\text{s}\cdot\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{I}\left(0\right)\right)\tag2$$

Comment: Can you explain to me the significance of the  I(0), the initial current for the inductor ? Because in some other examples I've seen they don't include that even though the Laplace of the derivative has it.

Comment: @MaizHalyym Well that is the initial condition in this circuit. So when there is an initial current trough the inductor it has to be placed there.